# Communicate with running process via STDOUT

Tags: python, linux

i have created a running process which listens for input:

```
listen = Popen(["home/user/listen"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

It runs and awaits input from STDIN/STDOUT.

Unfortunately, it seems that I can't execute anything I send to the process, i.e. like you would by pressing "Enter", e.g.

```
listen.communicate("Test")
```

or

```
listen.stdout("Test")
```

Writes the string to STDOUT but doesn't execute it, I have to press "Enter" manually. Any way to fix this?

P.S. I'm refering to http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Maybe send `"Test\n"` instead of `"Test"`?

Comment: Unfortuantely, this didn't work, it was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
listen.stdin.write("%s" %input)
listen.stdin.write("\n")
```

Comment: Try `listen.stdin.write("%s\n" % input)`.

Answer (score 1):

Does `home/user/listen` wait for the line end? If so, add `\n` at the end of your commands, like `listen.communicate("Test\n")`.

Comment: Yes I tried this, but it doesn't work. It does work if I write it in two lines, though...